# what to use insead of requestCode

Tags: java, android

hello i am trying to make a todo list and i have 2 activities ,i want to open the new activity in two ways
one way is to press the button and the other the recyclerView and they open the same activity but in the first you just add and in the second you update

before you could just insert the requestCode together with the intent like this :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
```

but now that startActivityForResult is deprecated i dont't know how to do it
and i searched a lot
Hre is my code until now  :

```
eActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // There are no request codes
                    Intent data = result.getData();

                    int id=data.getIntExtra(AddEditNoteActivity.EXTRA_ID,-1);
                    if(id == -1){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Note can't be updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    String title=data.getStringExtra(AddEditNoteActivity.EXTRA_TITLE);
                    String description = data.getStringExtra(AddEditNoteActivity.EXTRA_DESCRIPTION);
                    int priority = data.getIntExtra(AddEditNoteActivity.EXTRA_PRIORITY, 1);
                    Note note = new Note(title, description, priority);
                    noteViewModel.insert(note);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Note saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Note not saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }
        }
);
```

and here is what i want to do

```
 ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // action if button is clicked 
                    
                }else if() {
                    //action if recycledView is clicked
                }


            }
        }
);
```